# add visible sign in pdf from command line using imagemagick

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, imagemagick, sign

To sign pdf from command line in ubuntu I used '[signpdf](http://www.vromans.org/johan/software/sw_signpdf.html)'. The problem is that I need to add a visual to the document. Here is the solution I propose:

firma.sh

```
#!/bin/bash         

# add label
convert -rotate 90 -density 200 -quality 80 -gravity North -annotate +0+20 "Firmado por Félix José Hernández (`date`)" -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-R.ttf -pointsize 12 $1 _$1

# rotate normal
convert -rotate -90 -density 200 -quality 80 _$1 __$1

# sign
signpdf.jar __$1 s_$1 --certfile=/tmp/micertificado.pfx --password=$2

rm _$1 
rm __$1
```

And call:

firma.sh 001.pdf password

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is to add an image to the pdf file you should try something like:

```
 composite -gravity Center visual.png document.pdf result.pdf
```

this command adds an image centering it at the bottom of the pdf file.

---

EDIT:
To add a vertical text to your pdf document use this command:

```
convert test.pdf  -fill black -draw "translate 10,400 rotate 270 text 0,0 'Put your text here...'" output.pdf
```

where `translate x,y` represents margins on the x and y axes starting from the upper left corner (in the command above 10 points on the horizontal axis and 400 points on the vertical axis)

---

EDIT 2:
To address quality problems you can add `-density 200` and `-sharpen 0x1.0`, so your command would be:

```
convert -density 200 test.pdf -fill black -draw "translate 10,400 rotate 270 text 0,0 'Put your text here...'" -quality 80 -sharpen 0x1.0 output.pdf
```

Comment: Thank Andrea, I wanted to include a vertical text like this [link](http://picpaste.com/130528_convert-mbq1AvjO.jpg)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment: I edited my answer adding the command to add vertical text. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrea, it works!, but 'output.pdf' is of poor quality. I tested with '-density 200 -quality 80' but I am not convinced

Comment: @Félix José Hernández: I edited my answer trying to avoid output quality problems. Basically I added `-density 200` and  `-sharpen 0x1.0`; you should tweak these parameters to obtain expected result